# Inserting a variable into a request

Tags: string, dictionary, request, python-3.6

I have 2 variables:

```
minCount = 1
maxCount = 1000
```

I want to insert them into my request like so:

```
params = {'f': 'json', 'where': 'OBJECTID>=minCount and OBJECTID<=maxCount', 'geometryType': 'esriGeometryPolygon', 'spatialRel': 'esriSpatialRelIntersects','outFields': '*', 'returnGeometry': 'true'}
```

I've tried multiple variations of this, but it doesn't work (`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'format'` or `{'error': {'code': 400, 'message': 'Unable to complete operation.', 'details': []}}`):

```
params = {'f': 'json', 'where': 'OBJECTID>={minCount} and OBJECTID<={maxCount}', 'geometryType': 'esriGeometryPolygon', 'spatialRel': 'esriSpatialRelIntersects','outFields': '*', 'returnGeometry': 'true'}
```

What is the correct syntax to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved this. It was a bit tricky because the variable value still had to remain as a string, but here's what worked:

```
params = {'f': 'json', 'where': 'OBJECTID>='+str(minCount)+'and OBJECTID<='+str(maxCount), 'geometryType': 'esriGeometryPolygon', 'spatialRel': 'esriSpatialRelIntersects','outFields': '*', 'returnGeometry': 'true'}
```